# Java Recursion - counting Characters in a string

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to find the number of occurrences "character" is found in "str" using recursion. I think I have the concept of what to do but for some reason the code does not work when I test it out...do you know why its wrong?

```
   public static int countChar(String str, String character) {
    int number = 0;
    if(str.length()==1) {
        return number;
    }
    if (!(str.substring(0,1).equals(character))) {
        return countChar(str.substring(1), character);
    } else {
        number = number + 1;
        return countChar(str.substring(1), character);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Does not work", can you give more details? Expected output, actual output, errors, etc.

Comment: In what way does it not work? With what input, what is the expected and observed output?

Comment: Any reason you're doing this recursively? You can just do a simple loop...recursion doesn't offer too much advantage here.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit unclear. Basically it outputted 0 instead of whatever number it was supposed to output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

number is a local variable ....

```
 public static int countChar(String str, String character) {
    if(str.length()==0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if ((str.substring(0,1).equals(character))) {
        return 1 + countChar(str.substring(1), character);
    }

    return countChar(str.substring(1), character);
}
```

The terminating case is when the String length is zero.

For each step , check the current char , if match - add 1 to the result for the rest of the string, if not return the match result for the rest of the string

Answer (score 2):

In the `else` case, `number` is ignored after it's incremented.  But it's not needed anyway.  Just add one to whatever the recursive call returns.

```
} else {
    return 1 + countChar(str.substring(1), character);
}
```

Also, your base case should be if the string is empty, with a `length` of `0` returning `0`.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

1. The base case should probably be `str.length() == 0`, not `str.length() == 1`. While there's no right or wrong base case, it's easier here to get the right behavior for an empty string. Your behavior in the base case of length 1 strings is actually wrong; what if the length 1 string does contain character? Then you're missing it.
2. Your first `if` looks good; if it doesn't match the first character, return the result of `countChar` applied to the rest of the string.
3. Your second `if` isn't quite right; you want to return 1 plus the result of `countChar` applied to the rest of the string.

It looks like you've got one misconception that's making this harder than it needs to be: the way the code is written, you think that `number` retains its value in recursive calls. This isn't the case; every time you go into a new recursive call, the value of `number` is reset to 0. `number` is local to the function, which means that each recursive call gets its own copy to play with. If you want the recursive calls to get a value like that, you need to pass it as an argument, like you're doing with substrings.

Answer (score 1):

Code for what rgettman specified:

```
public static int countChar(String str, String character) {

    if(str.length() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (!(str.substring(0,1).equals(character))) {
        return countChar(str.substring(1), character);
    } else {
        return 1 + countChar(str.substring(1), character);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost

int number = 0;

Number is getting initialized to 0 on each call. Make it global or pass the value as a parameter in each call.